# A random sphere shows up in our atmosphere, and a nuke is fired at it. What happens to the sphere?

Tags: weapons

Assume that the ship is a perfect sphere, emits no radiation of any kind, and is made out of a material with equivalent strength to carbon nanotubes (both tensile and other). It is 1 kilometer in radius. It is made of the 'carbon nanotube' material all the way through, and is stationed 2 kilometers over, say, Manhattan. The nuke fired at it is the Tsar Bomba. Assume that the huge bomb is somehow lifted up and fired at the sphere, and hits in the EXACT center of of the bottom of the sphere (the side facing Manhattan).

- How much damage does it do to the sphere?
- How much damage does it do to Manhattan?
- Does the crew at the center of the sphere (with 0.9 kilometers between them and the bomb) survive?

Comment: It goes boooooom!!!

Comment: ? How much DAMAGE does it do to the sphere

Comment: It would melt it just like how fire melts a bar of chocolate and even if the spaceship is made of magic metal, the guys inside the spaceship are gonna be fried alive.

Comment: would it destroy the entire thing? its carbon nanotubes. those are INCREDIBLY heat resistant

Comment: ... its a non hollow sphere

Comment: A tsar bomba is many times hotter than a normal nuclear explosions, and a normal nuclear explosion reaches 100,000,000° Celsius.... Carbon nanotubes melt at 3500° Celsius.   A split second is enough to annihilate anything... Those things are hotter than the sun. A tsar bomba is absurddly overkill, something less powerful is enough to destroy them.

Comment: @user535733 this is a actual question i had, i thought this was the case, but i wanted to know for a story im making.

Comment: Seems like a perhaps-less-than-optimal solution to destroy most of NYC and kill around 10 million folks for this. Are we sure that *no other solutions* will have a better result? Like a sequential series of much smaller nukes, most against the top, that will leave most of Brooklyn and The Bronx intact? (and around 7-8 million alive). Or a deception to lure the sphere away to a better kill zone?

Comment: The sphere whatever, but *Manhattan* will be obliterated...

Comment: I edited your question for grammar and clarity. Note that you had an apparent inconsistency; the stated "one cubic kilometer" might mean either actual volume or that the sphere fits inside a cube one kilometer on a side, but your later statement that the crew at the center has 0.9 km between them and the bomb implies a 1 km radius (which would give a volume of ~4.19 km³). (Continued...)

Comment: (...) I changed the first figure to 1 km radius for consistency, and because it is more clear to either just give a radius (or diameter) or else clearly express that you are talking about volume and not a bounding box. If I guessed wrong, you should re-edit both numbers, but please check that they are consistent .

Comment: @Matthew Fortunately, at least for my answer, I think the dimensions are sufficiently large that both radius and diameter interpretations yield effectively the same outcome.

Comment: To clarify your figures, the bottom of the ship is two kilometre above Manhattan, and the top is four kilometres above Manhattan, and the crew compartment center is three kilometres above Manhattan?

Comment: This ship has a hell of a lot of inertia. However, an answer regarding the shock wave will need to address how much the ship moves upon impact. The more it moves in response to a pressure wave, the less effects the wave would have. F=ma, and there is a LOT of mass, which could absorb a LOT of force, for a small acceleration. If you put crushy spongy zones (layers) of corrugated nanotubes, lead (rads), gold (EMP) buffer layers in the sphere, and copper heat pipes to disperse the heat, this sphere ain't going nowhere. Manhattan, on the other hand, would take almost the full brunt of the blast.

Comment: " It [Tsar Bomba] exploded about 2.5 miles (4 km) above the ground, producing a mushroom cloud more than 37 miles (60 km) high; the flash of the detonation was seen some 620 miles (1,000 km) away. The resulting damage was equally massive. Severny, an uninhabited village 34 miles (55 km) from ground zero, was leveled, and buildings more than 100 miles (160 km) away were reportedly damaged. In addition, it was estimated that heat from the blast would have caused third-degree burns up to 62 miles (100 km) distant." https://www.britannica.com/topic/Tsar-Bomba

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sphere would fare pretty well.  Fundamentally, that's a very big solid mass, and they generally do pretty well against nuclear explosions.  We haven't really broken the earth yet with our nuclear tests!

There's [a few effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_nuclear_explosions) we can consider.  The first is the radiative heating effects.  Nuclear bombs are hot enough to vaporize things under the raw intensity of its black-body radiation.  This is most famous in the [rope trick effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_trick_effect), where ropes erupt into flames long before the flame front reaches them.

[image: Rope Trick Effect on Tumbler Snapper]

However impressive these effects look, a 1 cubic kilometer sphere isn't going to care much.  The outside layers are definitely going to erupt in flames, but we're not talking about meters of material, much less a kilometer.  They will explode outward as expected, but generally act as ablative insulation protecting the majority.  It literally takes too long to move all of that material out of the way.  The explosion ends (and temperatures drop) too soon.

The next thing to consider is the pressure effects.  Given that the bomb is going off mid-air, most of that will reflect off the impedance barrier between the air and the sphere.  So we really don't have to worry about that.  And the overpressure of a nuclear bomb, as big of a deal as it can be, is going to be a light tickle to a solid layer that thick.

So really the big thing that you'll be reliant on to do damage to the sphere is the shock wave effects.  The effect of these is not easy to account for in this case.  "Carbon nanotube" actually doesn't do all that much to help you... its the way to integrate the tubs together that matters.  A carbon nanotube rope has very different properties than a carbon nanotube impregnated epoxy.  Without knowing the particulars of how this sphere is built we can only guess what will happen.

In the end, a cubic kilometer of material is a *big* object.  Really big.  While a Tsar Bomba may be able to level buildings in a 10km radius, buildings are never made out of more than a meter of material, much less a kilometer.  This thing might as well be one big large bunker, and its designed to take it.

The last effect to consider would be radiation effects.  Once again, a kilometer is a lot.  A [reasonable fallout shelter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_protection) might have ten "halving thicknesses" of dirt, which is about 1m.  This cuts down radiation by a factor of a thousand, give or take.  10 meters of carbon would be more than sufficient to render any radioactive effects moot.  In fact, I would expect the small amount of radioactive carbon present to generate more radiation than would get through from the bomb!

What can a kilometer of carbon nanotubes do?  Well, consider this.  North Korea does nuclear testing underground.  We have [some information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_weapons_tests_of_North_Korea) about the depths they were testing at.  The deepest on the list was 1.3km underground.  It was estimated to be no more than a 200th of a Tsar Bomba, but it was protected by only dirt (rather than exotic metamaterials), and it was underground with nowhere for the pressure to go.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108108/discussion-on-answer-by-cort-ammon-a-random-sphere-shows-up-in-our-atmosphere-a).